# Create a column for every XML node that has no child nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssms

I am trying to query an xml file in SSMS to create a table that consists of the first row being the list of all xml nodes, and the next row containing all of its values. The xml data will have a repeating node that will create a new row for each repeating node with that name. Here's an example of the xml data:

```
<Tests>
<TestAnswers>
    <Question1>
        <Name>Example</Name>
        <Age>23</Age>
        <Question1B>
            <Title>Singer</Title>
        </Questions1B>
    </Question1>
    <Question2>
        <Car></Car>
        <Model>Model 1</Model>
        <Question2B>
            <Year>1986</Year>
            <Manufactured></Manufactured>
        </Questions2B>
    </Question2>
</TestAnswers>
<TestAnswers>
    <Question1>
        <Name>Santa</Name>
        <Age></Age>
        <Question1B>
            <Title>Writer</Title>
        </Questions1B>
    </Question1>
    <Question2>
        <Car>This car</Car>
        <Model>Model2</Model>
        <Question2B>
            <Year></Year>
            <Manufactured></Manufactured>
        </Questions2B>
    </Question2>
</TestAnswers>
</Tests>
```

The table I want to create in SQL Server should look something like:

```
   |    Name     | Age |    Title    |    Car    |    Model    |   Year   |    Manufactured    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Example     | 23  | Singer      |           | Model 1     | 1986     |                    |
 2 | Santa       |     | Writer      | This Car  | Model2      |          |                    |
```

There would be more rows that get created, as the xml file gets bigger with more information. I don't want to create columns for xml nodes that contain child nodes.

How can a write a query to perform this task?

**UPDATE**

New XML use case, where there there will be two columns made with duplicate nodes:

```
<Tests>
<TestAnswers>
    <Question1>
        <Name>Example</Name>
        <Age>23</Age>
        <Other>Other Text</Other>
        <Question1B>
            <Title>Singer</Title>
            <Other></Other>
        </Question1B>
    </Question1>
    <Question2>
        <Car></Car>
        <Model>Model 1</Model>
        <Question2B>
            <Year>1986</Year>
            <Manufactured></Manufactured>
        </Question2B>
    </Question2>
</TestAnswers>
<TestAnswers>
    <Question1>
        <Name>Santa</Name>
        <Age></Age>
        <Other></Other>
        <Question1B>
            <Title>Writer</Title>
            <Other>Text</Other>
        </Question1B>
    </Question1>
    <Question2>
        <Car>This car</Car>
        <Model>Model2</Model>
        <Question2B>
            <Year></Year>
            <Manufactured></Manufactured>
        </Question2B>
    </Question2>
</TestAnswers>
</Tests>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this XML under your control?

Besides the fact, that it is invalid (the closing tags for your sub-elements `<Question2B>` are in plural `<Questions2B>`) there are severe design flaws...

Most obvious is the *name numbering* like `<Question1>` and `<Question2>`...

And please provide some more details, if the content may vary too. You are writing *would be more rows* with *more information*. Do you mean *more of the same* or might there be other columns or even other structures too?

Besides all this here are some general approaches to show the principles:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Tests>
<TestAnswers>
    <Question1>
        <Name>Example</Name>
        <Age>23</Age>
        <Question1B>
            <Title>Singer</Title>
        </Question1B>
    </Question1>
    <Question2>
        <Car></Car>
        <Model>Model 1</Model>
        <Question2B>
            <Year>1986</Year>
            <Manufactured></Manufactured>
        </Question2B>
    </Question2>
</TestAnswers>
<TestAnswers>
    <Question1>
        <Name>Santa</Name>
        <Age></Age>
        <Question1B>
            <Title>Writer</Title>
        </Question1B>
    </Question1>
    <Question2>
        <Car>This car</Car>
        <Model>Model2</Model>
        <Question2B>
            <Year></Year>
            <Manufactured></Manufactured>
        </Question2B>
    </Question2>
</TestAnswers>
</Tests>';
```

--this will return all answers *row-by-row*

```
SELECT a.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('/Tests/TestAnswers') A(a);
```

--this will return all questions *row-by-row*

```
SELECT q.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('/Tests/TestAnswers') A(a)
OUTER APPLY a.nodes('*') B(q);
```

--this will return all nodes with an own text *row-by-row*

```
SELECT nd.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('/Tests/TestAnswers') A(a)
OUTER APPLY a.nodes('*') B(q)
OUTER APPLY q.nodes('//*[text()]') C(nd);
```

### UPDATE

Try this to get a list, then use `PIVOT` per `aInx` to get your tabular format:

```
WITH Answers AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS aInx
          ,a.query('.') AS a
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Tests/TestAnswers') A(a)
)
,Questions AS
(
    SELECT aInx
          ,q.query('.') AS q
    FROM Answers
    OUTER APPLY a.nodes('*') B(q)
)
SELECT aInx
      ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,nd.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM Questions
OUTER APPLY q.nodes('//*[text()]') C(nd);
```

Comment: Yes the XML is under my control. I created that sample XML just to give an idea of what kind of model I'll be trying to query. The amount of "TestAnswer" nodes can go up to over a hundred, and I want to be able to create a row of each repeating node under the "TestAnswer" name. However, each "TestAnswer" will have the exact same node structure, but different text data.

Comment: @Simon2233 Well, my given examples seem to do exactly this... Did you check this?

Comment: It seems to be getting all nodes with text values which is what you've stated. But how do I put it in a table format like the one in my question? Where each "TestAnswer" node will create a row with columns of nodes with own text. Note, that I want columns to still be created even if the xml node is empty. E.g. "<Manufactured></Manufactured>" should still create a column.

Comment: Is it possible to create a row entry even when there is an empty text to a node (example in my editted comment)? Also, whether the node name itself can be the column name (similar to my example in my question).

Comment: How would you go about changing the query, if the XML can have duplicate node names at different levels? See the XML in my updated question. I want to be able to make new column entries for each one of the duplicate nodes.